# How to make a browser send notification when you change the windows or tabs

Tags: javascript, python, django, function, web

So, I want to make a web app for tests. Usually students try to cheat so they change the tabs or open other apps and search for their info.So, I use fiverr, and you can take skill tests on fiverr and if you tried to change the browser, for example ALT + TAB the test would stop.How can I implement a function like that with django or js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript can help you, try:

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
      document.title = document.hidden ? "I'm away" : "I'm here";
});
```